# Apache Ignite's Continuous Queries event handler group & sequencing

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are trying to use the Continuous Query feature of Ignite. But we are facing an issue on handling that event. Below is our problem statement

- We have defined a Continuous Query with remote filter for a cache and shared the filter definition with Thick Client.
- We are running multiple replica of the "Thin Client" in Kubernetes cluster.
- Now the problem is each instance of the "Thin Client" running in k8s cluster have registered the remote filter and each instance receiving the event and trying to process the data in parallel. This resulting in duplicating data process or even overriding the data in my store.

Is there any way to form a consumer group and ensure that only one instance of the "Thin Client" is receiving the notification and its processing the data ?

My Thick client and Thin Clients are in .NET

Couldn't found any details on Ignite document

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/continuous-queries

Comment: It sounds like each thin client starts its own continuous query. A continuous query is guaranteed to deliver an event only once. see: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/continuous-queries#events-delivery-guarantees

Comment: Yes, each client starts its own continuous query. Is there any work around or configuration available to group this or sequence this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here each thin client is starting its own continuous query and thereby, by design, each thin client is getting its own event to consume. If you want to route an event to a specific client then you would need to start only one continuous query, and distribute that event to your app as you see fit. 
Take a look at [ignite messaging](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/messaging) to see whether it fits your use case.
Also check out the distributed [Queue/Se](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/queue-and-set)t which have unique delivery guarantees.