# Apache Ignite's Mixed-Platform Clusters limitation and Data Streaming

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are analyzing ignite to use it in .NET platform, In [Ignite document](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-platform-interoperability#mixed-platform-%20clusters) we can see there is some limitation on running cluster in Java and Thin Client in .NET. The list provided in the [document](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-platform-interoperability#mixed-platform-%20clusters) doesn't mention about "Data Streaming". So would like to know whether "Data Streaming" is supported in "Mixed-Platform" or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Data Streaming is supported in mixed-platform clusters, and you can do it from Ignite.NET Thin Client without any limitations.

P.S. The document is slightly outdated (fix on the way), Services are also supported in this scenario, you can make Java <-> .NET service calls in both directions, which some customers use extensively:
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-java-services-execution

Comment: Thanks for confirming, can you please help on one more query on continuous query 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75151680/apache-ignites-continuous-queries-event-handler-group-sequencing